# Return sql rows where field contains ONLY non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to find out how many rows in a particular field in my sql server table, contain ONLY non-alphanumeric characters.

I'm thinking it's a regular expression that I need along the lines of [^a-zA-Z0-9] but Im not sure of the exact syntax I need to return the rows if there are no valid alphanumeric chars in there.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions. It uses the LIKE pattern matching syntax which isn't the same.

As it happens, you are close. Just need leading+trailing wildcards and move the NOT

```
 WHERE whatever NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'
```

Comment: Wildcards shouldn't be there as he wants ONLY non-alpha numeric data

Comment: @cjk: corrected, I put the "negation" in the wrong place. this finds strings that don't have alphanumerics in

Comment: When `whatever` is the empty string (`''`) your predicate will select it i.e. does not contain any non-alphanumeric characters therefore should not be selected, according to the spec. Suggestion: `WHERE NULLIF(whatever, '') NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'`

Answer (score 2):

If you have short strings you should be able to create a few LIKE patterns (`'[^a-zA-Z0-9]'`, `'[^a-zA-Z0-9][^a-zA-Z0-9]'`, ...) to match strings of different length. Otherwise you should use CLR user defined function and a proper regular expression - [Regular Expressions Make Pattern Matching And Data Extraction Easier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This will not work correctly, e.g. `abcÑxyz` will pass thru this as it has a,b,c... you need to work with Collate or check each byte.