# TSQL Select national characters issue with the range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm on SQL Server 2016 with default settings, and can't understand whey this line 4 doesn't catch my weird character `Â`  which A with the roof. It's matched by [a-z] range, never thought that it would be the case. Is the any solution to work it out with the range ?  In my example below I expect to display single record, but line 4 doesn't allow me do so.  Is line 5 with the list the only solution???
Interesting that CHAR(13) is of of the range and works fine.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(10) = CHAR(13) +'Delta',   @b NVARCHAR(20) = 'Â' + 'Hotel';
SELECT @a A, LEN(@a) LenA, @b B, LEN(@b) LenB  
       ,CASE WHEN @b < 'A' THEN 'LessA'  ELSE CASE WHEN @b > 'Z' THEN 'GreaterZ' ELSE  'Â Between' END END sw
WHERE 1=1
AND    @b NOT LIKE  '[A-Z]%'             --- Line 4:   <<< 'Â'   in the range [a-z] or [A-Z] , how I can only work with 26 English letter range ???
-- AND    @b NOT LIKE  '[ABCDEFHGW]%'    --- Line 5:   <<< is writing the list the only solution ?
-- AND    @b LIKE 'Â%' 
-- COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

[image]

Comment: `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN`?

Answer (score 1):

It's still not working for 100% percent, need to be careful. COLLATE doesn't solve problem.  most reliable way to use  `LIKE '%[àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]%'`

Answer (score 0):

Found this which is perfect:
[SQL Query For Non-Alphabet name field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173246/sql-query-for-non-alphabet-name-field/66189167#66189167)

Check most recent post dd in 2021