# Return rows where field contains non alpha-numeric characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to extract all rows which contain a non alpha numeric character at it's most literal except allowing space. Any punctuation, brackets - square and round, currency symbols etc.

I have tried to adapt the advice as given here [Return sql rows where field contains ONLY non-alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157389/return-sql-rows-where-field-contains-only-non-alphanumeric-characters) however using `not LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%'` returns rows with a space. Fine. I amend the regex to be `not LIKE '%[a-z0-9 ]%'` and I now have zero rows returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That `LIKE` version is product specific...)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: apologies, edited to reflect we're using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you are referring to is for SQL Server.  To do what you want in SQL Server, you would do:

```
where col like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

The `^` in the like pattern matches any characters not in the list.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for the answer. So to include allowing spaces I can do `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'`. Should the rule need to be changed to allow specific punctuation, I take it I just add those characters on the end?

Comment: @GavinP `REGEX` is limited in T-SQL so I'd check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx and also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx to check the limitations.

Comment: @GavinP . . . You can add spaces and other characters between the square braces.  Be careful if you want to add square braces themselves.